# Why HTML element's attribute "title" not been named "tooltip"?

Tags: html, title

i think 'tooltip' would be more appropriate

Comment: It's a tooltip only when using graphical browsers. What about when you're parsing the code or crawlers or screen readers. It adds context in many ways. Also, offtopic :)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I think the question is appropriate, since it reveals a misunderstanding of html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's named title, because it is the title of an element.   In HTML, we describe what things are, not how to display them.  I do admit we didn't always do that, but we do it now, or at least should.

This is the same reasoning why to prefer the `<em>` tag over `<i>`.  It's more important to describe the meaning then the display.  The display is handled by the browser, and can be tweaked by CSS.

The fact that most browsers display `title` as a tooltip should be considered a detail.  Good to know of course.  But it's not a law; alternative browsers might do different things with it.  Classic cases are talking browsers and textual browsers.  But an example closer to home is iphone safari.  How can you have a tooltip when you don't have a hover?  I'm not sure what they do with the title attribute though.

Comment: Maybe of interest, html5 has designated semantic meanings to `<i>` and `<b>` now, [see here](http://html5doctor.com/i-b-em-strong-element/)

Answer (score 1):

a user agent may choose to implement showing title in statusbar or may not show at all. its up to user agent

Answer (score 1):

Back in the day, the title attribute didn't make a tooltip. It displayed elsewhere, such as in the status bar, or even not at all. Over time the behaviour has become more consistent across browsers making a tooltip.